# error in json format in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var createError = require('http-errors')


 app.use(bodyParser.json());


 Genre=require('./model/genre')
Book=require('./model/book')

//connect to Mongoose
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore', { useMongoClient: true});
var db=mongoose.connection;


 /*  "/api/books"
 *    GET: finds all books
 *    POST: creates a new book
  */
 app.get('/api/books',function(req,res){
 Book.getBook(function(err,book){
 if(err){

     throw err; //Want this error in json format
 }
  //JSON response will show all books in JSON format
 res.json(book);
    });
  });




     //Connection to the mongodb localhost
  app.listen(27017);
   console.log('Running on port 27017');

  error is:
    TypeError: Book.getBook is not a function
```

Please tell me how to throw error in json format as am new to mongodb.....
I am using visual studio for the changes
With that mongodb+node.js+express
Want error should display in the json format....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here is the way to throw error in json.

```
  app.get('/api/books',function(req,res,callback){
    Book.getBooks(function(err,book){
     if(err){
         res.status(404).send({ error: 'error in mongo of kalpita!' });

          }else{
          //JSON response will show all books in JSON format
            res.json(book);
           }
        },10);
      });
```

and also add

Book.find({},callback).limit(limit);

in model.

Comment: using above code i am getting the same TypeError. Is there any change that I have to do?
My error:
TypeError: Book.getBook is not a function

Comment: check this out add callback in app.get and send by callback.

Comment: If it is saying TypeError: Book.getBook  is not function than the Book file is not imported properly . Add the code of Book model let me check

Comment: below is my book.js file:
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//Book Schma as per the db fields
// create instance of Schema
var bookSchma = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    genre:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    create_date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});

// create model if not exists.
var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Book',bookSchma);

//Get Book
module.exports.getBooks =function(callback,limit){
    Book.find(callback).limit(limit);
}

Comment: @kalpita check out now. Your function name was wrong and pass limit with function , i have updated code.

Comment: It is right but i am not able to get at what condition should I check this error??

Comment: for now test if(true) , In most case we check for err with data == null , err will come in very less cases but that is other question , write if(true) it will go in error .

Comment: error: throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Comment: ok check the code add else condition in the code . ok. This error is for muliple callback send.

Comment: your code is running..But error is not coming in json format

check error:
BadRequest: null
    at C:\Users\iariana6\apis\bookstore\app.js:57:20
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\iariana6\apis\bookstore\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3805:16)
    at C:\Users\iariana6\apis\bookstore\node_modules\kareem\index.js:273:21
    at C:\Users\iariana6\apis\bookstore\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Comment: if callback not working in your case use res.json(400, {
    error: err.message // err
  });

Comment: tried with res.json

     if(true){
       var error = new Error(err); // new Error(err);
          error.name = 'BadRequest';
          error.httpStatusCode = 400;
          res.json(err);
          
     
      }else{
          //JSON response will show all books in JSON format
            res.json(book);
      }

Getting error: null

Is this right??? will I get json error at the time of actual error?

Comment: No json will come now also it has nothing to do with actual error time . Can you do this res.status(404).send({ error: 'error in mongo of kalpita!' }); in place of callback

Comment: yes it is working...
{
error: "error in mongo of kalpita!"
}